# How to increment a counter in Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a chat app like, and here all users have their own `followers` and `following`.

Now I want to make a counter for `followers`, as a user follow someone the counter gets increased, but there my concern is, if 100 users follow a same user at the same time, what will be happened?

Will counter incremented 100 time or not?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you increment the counter.  If you use [FieldValue.increment()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#increment), then there will be no problems.  If you use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), there will be no problems.  But if you read the document, increment in memory, then update the field, there could be a collision that loses data.

Comment: I am creating one doc when one user follow another user on that time I increment by one at the time a user `follow` another user, example, `user1, user2, ... user100` follow `user500` at the same time, will it be increment to 100 ?, because they followed at the same time. I am not reading a document then Increment then write. I am using `FieldValue.increment()`